# Rest-Assured testing - Variables dinamicas en el Json Data

Tags: java, json, restful, testing, cucumber

Tengo un json data con valores en duro, quiero hacer dinamicos los campos como "personId" y "ticketID" y que puedan cambiar de acuerdo a datos que haya en responses de peticiones anteriores a esta:

```
{
  "personId": 11621,
  "isPrincipalPayer": true,
  "personTempId": null,
  "toddlerId": null,
  "passengerCode": null,
  "tickets": [
    {
      "ticketId": 2045254,
      "multiRef": null,
      "ticketRef": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Que es consumido en el feature para realizar una peticion POST :

```
# asignar pasajero a ticket
    Y que se envia un payload con la consulta "ticket-assign-passenger-data"
    Dado que se envia una peticion POST a /web/passenger/ticket-assign-web
```

Y lo consulta en el definition:

```
//ticket-office
@Y("que se envia un payload con la consulta {string}")
public void queSeEnviaUnPayloadConLaConsulta(String archivo) {
    file = new File("src/test/resources/json-data/ticket-office/" + archivo + ".json");
}
```